# Parse a semicolon separated file in Java

Tags: java, excel

I have a excel file and the contents are shown below. 
First line is header, second line on wards is the data.

```
Cell A1 contains line below (Header)
**IsShooting; Velocity; Location_x; Location_y; Location_z; Onslaught_ONSAV ; ***Event***; EventParams...**

Cell A2 contains below
0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.000;0.000;0;0.000;0.000;None;0;0;0.000;-1983.610;-

Cell A3 Contains below
;0.250;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;***BOT_KILLED***;CTF-Geothermal.GBxBot10;XWeapons.DamTypeFlakChunk

Cell A4 Contains below
4.110;161.900;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;0.000;4.320;0.000;0.260;0.000;0.000;***FLAG_PICKEDUP***;0;CTF-Geothermal.GBxBot10
```

I want to know if there are any open Source CSV Parsers, I can use so that, I can get the data from the excel.

The above excel file contains 400 lines of data. All I want from this is the COUNT of FLAG_PICKEDUP & BOT_KILLED.

Thanks!

Comment: Google can help u better, there are plenty of csv parsers for Java. Apache can be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest way I can think of. Use a BufferedReader to read each line. For each line split it into a String array, then check each String to see if it equals the constants that define flag pickups or bot kills.

I think Apache makes csv parser, but I've never used it. For something this simple it might just be easier to code it yourself. This is what I came up with in about 5 mins.

NOTE: All due respect, stackoverflow generally asks that you attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Since you didn't post code, we can't help you debug and we don't know if you tried to solve the problem yourself. This was simple, so I helped but you may find it easier to get support if you post your (failed) solution first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
        int botKilledCount = 0, flagPickedUpCount = 0;
        String line, botLiteral = "***BOT_KILLED***", flagLiteral = "***FLAG_PICKEDUP***";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("!!YOUR FILE HERE!!")));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            for (String s : line.split(";"))
                if (s.equals(botLiteral))
                    botKilledCount++;
                else if (s.equals(flagLiteral))
                    flagPickedUpCount++;

        System.out.println("Bot Killed Count: " + botKilledCount + ", Flag Pickup Count: " + flagPickedUpCount);
}
```

This was the output:

```
Bot Killed Count: 1, Flag Pickup Count: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I was trying to use some CSV Parser. But this helps me for now. :-)